# Why Superman was not affected by kryptonite in this scene?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the film [Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/) Superman was significantly weakened (and nearly died) when he tried to dive down into the water to retrieve the Kryptonite spear, but in a subsequent scene he flew with it and seems to have suffered no ill effects.

**How did Superman manage to fly with kryptonite spear equipped?**

Comment: Two good questions.

Comment: Super adrenaline?

Comment: At the time I simply assumed he'd had a chance to recover so he could better resist its effects for a brief time, but it was probably still weakening him, and that may have been a factor in how effectively Doomsday hurt him in that same scene.

Comment: Because he tried harder, which seems to be just for purposes of the plot. Same way he almost died vs. Kevin Spacey by standing on the island but then able to lift said deadly island out of the water, injured.

Comment: He didn't look like he was flying very well with it. Low to the ground and kept dropping altitude, i got the impression it was taking him a lot of effort to do it and by the time he used the spear he looked almost at the end of his abilities to do anything

Answer (score 7):

In universe it's likely that Superman was just trying harder as he begins to tire near the end.

The out of universe answer is, however, more likely. Out of universe it's because this film is filled with plot holes.

Answer (score 2):

He is, you can see that he struggles to fly, having to push himself up off the ground with his hands at one point. He also has a grimace on his face and he was stabbed by Doomsday which wouldn't normally work due to his near unbreakable skin.